# Why the following Tensorflow code produces the shown result?

Tags: tensorflow

I am following the tensorflow tutorial to do some tests. In the section of Variable of the official [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/basic_usage.html), there is a code snippet indicating how to use tensorflow to implement a counter. I changed it a little bit so that the result changed as follows. However, I don't know the logic behind.

The specific line of the code I changed is `state = tf.add(state, one)`. I think when `sess.run(state)` is called, the `add` operation should be executed multiple times, producing the result `0 1 2 3`. However, it was still `1 1 1 1`. Any explanations?

```
import tensorflow as tf
state = tf.Variable(0, name="counter")
one = tf.constant(1)
state = tf.add(state, one)
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    print(sess.run(state))
    for _ in range(3):
        print(sess.run(state))
```

The output is

```
1
1
1
1
```

---

Follow-ups

```
import tensorflow as tf
state = tf.Variable(0, name="counter")
one = tf.constant(1)
new_value = tf.add(state, one)
state = tf.assign(state, new_value) ## <== (1)
#state = tf.add(0, new_value) ## <== (2)

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    for _ in range(4):
        print(state.eval())
```

If run with line `(1)` but no `(2)`, the result is `1 2 3 4`;

If run with line `(2)` but no `(1)`, the result is `1 1 1 1`;

Why?

Answer (score 1):

The result is indeed correct.

When you define

```
state = tf.Variable(0, name="counter")
one = tf.constant(1)
state = tf.add(state, one)
```

You are defining a graph of ordered operations such as:

1. state = 0
2. one = 1
3. state = state+one

After the graph definition, `state` holds the the last operation of the graph, not the numerical value of `tf.add(state, one)`.

Therefore, when you run `sess.run(state)` in a loop, you are asking Tensorflow to run the graph you have created many times, but the operations graph will be always the same, so the result is always the same.

---

### Follow-ups

Ok, lets see what's happening in both scenarios `(1)` and `(2)` for the code you provided.

```
import tensorflow as tf
state = tf.Variable(0, name="counter")
one = tf.constant(1)
new_value = tf.add(state, one)
state = tf.assign(state, new_value) ## <== (1)
#state = tf.add(0, new_value) ## <== (2)

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    for _ in range(4):
        print(state.eval())
```

**Scenario (1)**

In this scenario you are calling 4 times `state.eval()`. What is state? Well, it is a Variable because you have previously initialized it to:

```
state = tf.Variable(0, name="counter")
```

Then with the line (1) `state = tf.assign(state, new_value)` what you are doing is giving a value to this Variable. The [documentation for tf.assign()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#assign) says that it returns the same Variable, so after the line (1) state is still the same Variable as before, only that now it has the value `new_value`.
Then what is `new_value`? It's just the result of adding 1 to the Variable `state` as you have defined in `new_value = tf.add(state, one)`.

Now we can see what happens if you eval `state` four times:

Iteration 0:

- `state` has an initial value of 0
- `new_value` is an operation which defines `state`+1 so it has value 1 when evaluated.
- With `tf.assign` you set `state` to the value of `new_value`, so it is 1 now.
- `print(state.eval())` prints `1` because this is the current value of `state`.

Iteration 1:

- `state` was `1` in the previous iteration.
- `state` has the same value of `new_value` because of tf.assign().
- As `new_value` is `state`+`1`, now it has a value of 2.
- `print(state.eval())` prints `2` because this is the current value of `state`.

Iteration 2:

- `state` was `2` in the previous iteration.
- ...

**Scenario (2)**

What's going on here is that you are overriding the initial `state` which is a tensorflow Variable with the operation `tf.add`, so the code is no longer doing what you expect. Let me explain.

First `state` is a Variable with value `0` as initialized in:

```
state = tf.Variable(0, name="counter")
```

and `new_value` is an operation which defines `state`+`1`, so it is has a value of `1` when evaluated.
Then you override `state` by assigning it to the operation `tf.add(0, new_value)`. Why is that important? Well, because `new_value` depends on `state`, yes, but it depends on the content of `state` before overriding it, so it is using the "old" `state` which is a Variable with value `0`.

Hence, when you call `state.eval()` four times you are evaluating `tf.add(0, new_value)` four times, and its result is always `1` because `new_value` is always `1`, as the value of "old" `state` is not changing.

Comment: "After the graph definition, state holds the the last operation of the graph, not the numerical value of tf.add(state, one)", when does state represent the numerical value?

Comment: Or, may I interpret it as that, in step 1 and step 3, i.e. state = 0 and state = state + one, state represents different meanings?

Comment: `state` will represent the numerical value only once you evaluate it, like with `state = sess.run(state)`. Yes, in step 1 and 3 state represents differents things. In step 1 `state` is a Variable initialized to zero, and in step 3 it is the operation `tf.add(state, one)`. Actually, in step 3 you are overriding the initial value of the python variable `state` with another value.

Comment: see my follow-ups of this question. Actually I am still confused with this code.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the follow-ups, I hope it is clearer now.